# send html as attachment via phpmailer

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I have html variable,i want to send it as attachment via email.

here is my code

```
$html='
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style=" margin:0 auto;" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="background:#FC3; padding:4px 0;border:1px solid #000; border-bottom:2px solid #000; border-right:2px solid #000;" align="center" valign="middle"><h3 style="font:300 14px verdana; margin:0; text-align:left;text-align:center;">DECLARATION BY THE AGENT</h3></th>
        <th style="background:#FC3; padding:4px 0;border:1px solid #000; border-bottom:2px solid #000; border-right:2px solid #000;" align="center" valign="middle"><h3 style="font:300 14px verdana; margin:0; text-align:left;text-align:center;">DECLARATION BY THE OWNER (The Seller)</h3></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="49%" style="padding:5px 10px;border-right:2px solid #000;">
        <ul style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <li style="list-style:none; margin:0 0 10px 0;">
                <p style="font:300 12px verdana;float: left; margin:0 5px 0 0;text-align:center;">
                    I hereby declare, I have read and understood the Real Estate Brokers Code of Ethics,

                </p>
            </li>
        </ul></td>
        <td width="49%" style="padding:5px 10px;border-left:1px solid #000;">
        <ul style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <li style="list-style:none; margin:0 0 10px 0;">
                <p style="font:300 12px verdana;float: left; margin:0 5px 0 0; text-align:center;">
                    I/We hereby declare, we are the Owners of the property as stated below.
                </p>

            </li>

        </ul></td>
    </tr>
</table>';

$mail->AddAttachment($html); // attachment
$mail->Send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddAttachment()` requires a file (on the filesystem)

there is the `AddStringAttachment()` function for what you are doing. see docs: http://docs.redaxo.com/de/4.3.1/class_p_h_p_mailer.html#a92ef5134fdce5bd5fd24a723c508bf2b

try this:

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment($html,"filename.htm","base64","text/html");
```

Comment: Basically i want to send this html form to client so that he can download and fill it..

Comment: have you tried it? it should add `filename.htm` with your html code from `$html` as an attachment to your email. thats what you want isnt it?

Comment: yes it works,but when we download it,images are missing...Is there any other way so that i can send this form?

Comment: of course the images are missing, you dont send them! simply link the images with an absolute url. Use `src="http://www.yourdomain.com/img.jpg"` instead of `src="img.jpg"`

Comment: can we send it with other type like filename.pdf OR filename.csv etc etc?

Comment: you can send what you want, i would always recommend PDFs for Documents, they have many advantages over html, but are much harder to generate (depending on complexity)

Comment: I tried to generate pdf via TCPDF,but here are alot of issue in html and css...that is why i want to send it in some other format?now please suggest me what to do?

Comment: html will work fine, just make sure everything that is linked within the html is linked with the absolute url (including `http://www.yourdomain.com/..`). i would personally prefer PDFs, because its better for printing and it looks more professional. but its also more work. html -> pdf conversion is always problematic, so generating the pdf by hand is ofter preferable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to send html instead so try like this

```
   $mail->Body = $html;
   $mail->Send();
```

ok, so you are trying to send it for example and it deosn't work ?

```
  $mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.html");
```

Comment: This was just an example..i have a complete html form/page..i want to send it to client so that he can download and fill that form